# Daylight saving issue while calculating Elapsed Time in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to calculate elapsed time for my project.
For example,
Start time is 06-Nov-2011 01:59:58 A.M
End Time is 06-Nov-2011 01:00:00 A.M
Actual Elapsed Time is 00:00:02
But getting Elapsed Time is -00:59:58 (Due to Daylight Saving, clock went back 1 hour)
How can i calculate this in better way with correct elapsed time during Daylight Saving?

**Code:**

```
DateTime startDttm = DateTime.Parse("Nov 06, 2011 01:59:58 AM");  
DateTime endDttm = DateTime.Parse("Nov 06, 2011 01:00:00 AM");  
TimeSpan elapsedTime = endDttm.Subtract(startDttm);  
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time - " + elapsedTime);
```

Comment: first convert it to unix timestamp then calculate it.

Comment: check for Noda time api. http://noda-time.blogspot.in/

Comment: Tried Converting it to UTC, like startDttm.ToUniversalTime(); end.ToUniversalTime(); then tried Subtract(), also giveing the same result.

Comment: You need to take the timezone into account when doing the conversion.

Comment: @Vinoth: Your calculation is fundamentally ambiguous. For example, if your times had been 01:30:00 and 01:45:00 then the right answer *could* be either 15 minutes or 1 hour and 15 minutes. Such is the problem of using local date/times. Do you *have* to?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yep i know this is ambiguous, how can i avoid this, if any process started before daylight saving & ends after daylight saving. Then only i have to calculate in the way i explained earlier, not the later one what you explained.

Comment: @Vinoth: You'll have to make the *data* unambiguous: the easiest way is to record UTC time instead of local time.

Answer (score 6):

Your values are basically ambiguous - both of those times occurred *twice* assuming the clocks went back at 2am.

If you know that you want to treat the start time as the *earlier* option, and the end time as the *later* option, you can use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/):

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo
              ("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
        LocalDateTime start = pattern.Parse("Nov 06, 2011 01:59:58 AM").Value;
        LocalDateTime end = pattern.Parse("Nov 06, 2011 01:00:00 AM").Value;

        DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.ForId("America/Chicago");

        // Where this is ambiguous, pick the earlier option
        ZonedDateTime zonedStart = zone.AtEarlier(start);

        // Where this is ambiguous, pick the later option
        ZonedDateTime zonedEnd = zone.AtLater(end);

        Duration duration = zonedEnd.ToInstant() - zonedStart.ToInstant();

        // Prints 00:00:02
        Console.WriteLine(duration.ToTimeSpan());
    }        
}
```

In an ideal world, however, you wouldn't be having to parse ambiguous local times and guess whether they're meant to be earlier or later. What's the context here?

If *at all* possible, change your data source to record UTC date/times instead of local dates/times... ideally in a more parse-friendly format, e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

Comment: Jon, don't you want zone.AtLater(end)?

Comment: @IanHorwill: Oops, yes :) And now the elapsed time is as requested. I must have been half asleep when writing this answer - apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Use Coordinated Universal Time to store your timestamps. Whenever you compare two timestamps in Coordinated Universal Time, you get the correct difference.

In C# you get the current timestamp in that format by using `DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow`.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time.